# Help understanding sufficient statistic proof

Tags: probability, statistics, sufficient-statistics

I am having a hard time following this proof, maybe the solutions have jumped some steps but was wondering if someone could help me follow it.

The question:

let $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ be independent and identically distributed sequence of random variables from a population where $g_{\theta}(x) = 2^{{\theta}-x-1}$ where $x \in (\theta, \theta+1,\theta+2...)$

Show that the statistic $T_{2}(\vec{X}) = max (X_{1},X_{2})$ is not sufficient for $\theta_{0}$

We note that $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ are independent and that $T_{2}(\vec{X})$ only depends on $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$. Therefore, the distribution of $X_{3}$ conditional on $T_{2}(\vec{X})$ is the same as $g_{\theta}$. Since the original $g_{\theta}$ depends on $\theta$ we conclude that the distribution of $X_{3}$ conditional on $T_{2}(\vec{X})$ also depends on $\theta$ and thus $T_{2}$ is not a sufficient statistic.

Proof that distribution depends on $\theta$

If $P(X_{3} = x) = 2^{{\theta}-x-1}$, which depends on $\theta$

$E[X_{3}] = \sum_{x=\theta}^{\inf}x2^{{\theta-x-1}}$ = $\sum_{x=0}^{\inf}(x+\theta)2^{{-x-1}} = \sum_{x=1}^{\inf}x2^{{-x-1}}+\sum_{x=1}^{\inf}\theta2^{-x}$ = $2^{-1}\sum_{x=1}^{\inf}x2^{-x} +\sum_{x=1}^{\inf}\theta2^{-x} = 2+\theta$

But I am unsure how they got the last line of this proof?

Was hoping someone could help fill in the blanks.

Many thanks.

Comment: Any ideas? My teacher says it has something to do with the geometric series, but I do not see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a factor of $2^{-1}$ was dropped, either in the solution or your typing it out here. Maybe that's the trouble? Recall from calculus that for $|r| < 1$,

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^n = \frac{r}{1-r}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nr^n = \frac{r}{(1-r)^2}\\
$$

So,

$$
\begin{align}
E[X] &= \sum_{x = \theta}^{\infty}x2^{\theta-x-1}\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}(x+\theta)2^{-x-1}\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}x2^{-x-1} + \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\theta2^{-x-1}\\
&=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x2^{-x-1} + \theta2^{-1}+\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\theta2^{-x-1}\\
&=2^{-1}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x2^{-x} + \theta 2^{-1} + \theta2^{-1}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}2^{-x}\\
&=2^{-1}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) ^x + \theta 2^{-1} + \theta2^{-1}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^{x}\\
&= 1 + \theta 2^{-1} + \theta 2^{-1}\\
& = 1 + \theta
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Many thanks for this! Just to clarify, what is happening from line 3 to line 4?

Comment: At $x = 0$, the first term in the left sum equals $0$ because it is multiplied by $x$. The first term in the right sum equals $\theta 2^{0-1}$. We remove both of those terms from the sums, so that the sums start at $x = 1$.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for this!

Comment: @StephenMoreton, if you're satisfied with this answer, could you click the check-mark near the top left of the answer? That marks the [answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and removes the question from the list of unanswered questions.